# How to join tables using laravel eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel

**code:**

```
function viewPDF()
{
$reports = Report::with([
        'quarters' => function($query) {
            // filters on quarters table
            return $query->where('column', 'value');
        },
        'presidents' => function($query) {
            // filters on presidents table
            return $query->where('column', 'value');
        }
    ])
    ->filter()  // only for reports table
    ->latest()
    ->get();

$pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.test1', ['reports' => $reports]);
return $pdf->stream('reports.pdf');
}
```

I want to do by Eloquent way. Please, how could I do?

**1-Table** `quarters`

```
Schema::create('quarters', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('quarter_report', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('quarter_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('report_id')->unsigned();
    $table->primary(['quarter_id' , 'report_id']);
});
```

**2- Table** `presidents`

```
Schema::create('presidents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->string('P_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
 Schema::create('president_report', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('president_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('report_id')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(['president_id','report_id']);
    });
```

**3- Table** `reports`

```
Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('target_value');
        $table->text('major_activity');
        $table->string('indicator');
        $table->string('responsibility');
        $table->string('progress_activity');
        $table->string('documents')->nullable();
        $table->string('percentage_activity')->nullable();
        $table->text('problem')->nullable();
        $table->text('solution')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('image')->default('default.png');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('0');
        $table->tinyInteger('active')->default('0');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Report Model**

```
class Report extends Model
{

public function quarters() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Quarter', 'quarter_report', 'report_id', 'quarter_id');
}

public function presidents() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\President', 'president_report', 'report_id', 'president_id');
}

public function scopeFilter($query){
    $president = request('president');
    if ( isset($president)&& trim($president) != '' && $president != 'all'){
        $query->whereHas('presidents' , function ($query )use ($president){
            $query->whereId($president);
        });
    }
    $quarter = request('quarter');
    if ( isset($quarter)&& trim($quarter) != '' && $quarter != 'all'){
        $query->whereHas('quarters' , function ($query )use ($quarter){
            $query->whereId($quarter);
        });
    }


  }
```

**President Model**

```
class President extends Model
{

public function reports() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Report', 'president_report', 'president_id', 'report_id');
}
}
```

**Quarter Model**

```
class Quarter extends Model
{
public function reports() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Report', 'quarter_report',  'quarter_id', 'report_id');
}
 }
```

Comment: `president_report as pr` you might want to write `presidents`, here. you have not write the `presidents` anywhere in the joins that's why you are getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to join the `presidents` table with `president_report` table. But you joined `president_report` table twice. Correct way should be

```
$reports = Report::join('president_report', 'reports.id', '=','president_report.report_id')
    ->join('presidents', 'presidents.id', '=', 'president_report.president_id')
    ->join('quarter_report', 'president_report.report_id', '=', 'quarter_report.report_id')
    ->latest('reports.created_at')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I tried this way Unfortunately it gave error message

Comment: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `reports` inner join `president_report` on `reports`.`id` = `president_report`.`report_id` inner join `presidents` on `presidents`.`id` = `president_report`.`president_id` inner join `quarter_report` on `president_report`.`report_id` = `quarter_report`.`report_id` order by `created_at` desc)`

Comment: use `created_at` in the `latest()` from which table you want the latest data.

Comment: Filter does not work I want to filter reports by president and quarter then print. This code prints all reports

Comment: you can use `orderBy` for your filtering. write your own filter logic.

Comment: `public function scopeFilter($query)
    {
        $president = request('president');
        if (isset($president) && trim($president) != '' && $president != 'all') {
            $query->whereHas('presidents', function ($query) use ($president) {
                $query->whereId($president);
            });
        }
        $quarter = request('quarter');
        if (isset($quarter) && trim($quarter) != '' && $quarter != 'all') {
            $query->whereHas('quarters', function ($query) use ($quarter) {
                $query->whereId($quarter);
            });
        }
    } `

Answer (score 0):

You are not joining `presidents` table..Include that too..

```
 $reports = DB::table('president_report')
 ->join('reports', 'reports.id', '=', 'president_report.report_id')
 ->join('quarter_report', 'president_report.report_id', '=', 'quarter_report.report_id')
 ->join('presidents','president_report.president_id','=','presidents.id')
 ->select('president_report.*','reports.*','quarter_report.*','presidents.id','presidents. P_name')
 ->latest('reports.created_at')
 ->get();
```

Comment: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `president_report`.*, `reports`.*, `quarter_report`.*, `presidents`.* from `president_report` inner join `reports` on `reports`.`id` = `president_report`.`report_id` inner join `quarter_report` on `president_report`.`report_id` = `quarter_report`.`report_id` inner join `presidents` on `president_report`.`president_id` = `presidents`.`id` order by `created_at` desc)`

Comment: created_at is present in both presidents and reports table.Which created_at field is required for ordering ?

Comment: I want filtering by presidents  and quarters

Comment: I tried again  the error message   `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter(`

Comment: Then remove filter() from the join query and after getting results you can perform filtering..

Comment: I removed filter `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `president_report`.*, `reports`.*, `quarter_report`.*`

Comment: I think there is created_at fields are present in multiple tables.so whichever created_at is you required to order,specify that in `latest` function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use laravel eloquent use as below:

In Report.php

```
class Report extends Model 
{
    public function quarters() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Quarter', 'quarter_report', 'report_id', 'quarter_id');
    }

    public function presidents() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\President', 'president_report', 'report_id', 'president_id');
    }

}
```

In Quarter.php

```
class Quarter extends Model 
{
    public function reports() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Report', 'quarter_report', 'quarter_id', 'report_id');
    }


}
```

In President.php

```
class President extends Model 
{
    public function reports() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Report', 'president_report', 'president_id', 'report_id');
    }

}
```

In Controller

```
function viewPDF()
{
    $reports = Report::with(['quarters', 'presidents']);

    if ( request('president') ) {
        $reports = $reports->whereHas('presidents' , function ($query) {
            $query->whereId( request('president') );
        });
    }

    if ( request('quarter') ) {
        $reports = $reports->whereHas('quarters' , function ($query) {
            $query->whereId( request('quarter') );
        });
    }

    $reports = $reports->latest()
        ->get();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.test1', ['reports' => $reports]);
    return $pdf->stream('reports.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Filter does not work I want to filter reports by president and quarter then print. This code prints all reports

Comment: Updated code to filter by president and quarter. (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: I added my Model and filter code please check.
Filter does not work I want to filter reports by president and quarter. then all records print from reports table

Comment: share your filter scope of model.

Comment: I shared filter scope in Report model

Comment: `public function scopeFilter($query){
    $president = request('president');
    if ( isset($president)&& trim($president) != '' && $president != 'all'){
        $query->whereHas('presidents' , function ($query )use ($president){
            $query->whereId($president);
        });
    }
    $quarter = request('quarter');
    if ( isset($quarter)&& trim($quarter) != '' && $quarter != 'all'){
        $query->whereHas('quarters' , function ($query )use ($quarter){
            $query->whereId($quarter);
        });
    }`